# SQL query taking too long, are there any optimizations possible, need to be pointed into right direction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

**Question**

I recently learned about CTE's and how to use them for performance winning, however I think I am overusing them in this case. The below query is taking about 1 minute with only 1000 examinations and I am sure it can be done much faster. Please suggest optimizations or terms that can point me in the right direction?

**Context**

To understand the query, you need to have some context so here it is. In the database we have **examinations** which will be performed on an **object** (E.G. a pen needs to be examinated if it can write). Before an examination can start an examination must be acknowledged so there is the **acknowledged date**. Of course we also save when an examination is created (**createdate**). When an examination is ready (**Ready Date**) it needs to get a result. A result can be approved (**isapproved**) or rejected (**isrejected**). The meaning of this query is to create graph which shows the 5 conditions of examinations per day.

Counts needed per day:

1. examinations_created_count
2. examinations_acknowledged_count
3. examinations_ready_count
4. examinations_ready_and_approved_count
5. examinations_ready_and_rejected_count

**Actual Query**

```
DECLARE @ProjectID [bigint] = 3
DECLARE @LocationID [bigint] = 2
DECLARE @PersonID [bigint] = 1058
DECLARE @StartDate [datetime] = '2012-01-01' 
DECLARE @EndDate [datetime]= '2014-12-31'

;WITH ExaminationCTE(acknowledgedate, readydate, createdate, isrejected, isapproved) 
AS
(
    SELECT [acknowledgedate], [readydate], createdate, [isrejected], [isapproved]  FROM [dbo].[Examination]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Object] [o] ON [dbo].[Examination].[fk_objectid] = [o].[pk_objectid]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ExaminationResults] [er]  ON [dbo].[Examination].[fk_examinationid] = [er].[pk_examinationid]
    WHERE [fk_projectid] = @ProjectID 
    AND [fk_locationid] = @LocationID 
    AND [fk_personid] = @PersonID
),
dates(Date) AS 
(
    --Get all the dates between the selected range
    SELECT @StartDate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,[Date])
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATE < @EndDate
)

-- Select all the counts from the examination CTE
SELECT d.Date,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ExaminationCTE] WHERE [createdate] <= [d].[Date]) AS 'examinations_created_count',
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ExaminationCTE] WHERE [acknowledgedate] <= [d].[Date]) AS 'examinations_acknowledged_count',
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ExaminationCTE] WHERE [readydate] <= [d].[Date]) AS 'examinations_ready_count',
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ExaminationCTE] WHERE [readydate] <= [d].[Date] AND [isapproved] = 1) AS 'examinations_ready_and_approved_count',
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ExaminationCTE] WHERE [readydate] <= [d].[Date] AND [isrejected] = 1) AS 'examinations_ready_and_rejected_count'      
FROM dates d
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

While the query is working at the moment it isn't meeting my performance specs. I feel this can be done neater.

**UPDATE:**
Due to the help of @GordonLinoff I'm almost there. However I need to fill the NULL rows with the last possible value.

[image: This image shows what the null values must be]

In the image you can see the results are null the arrows, points out what the value should be, for the first set of NULL I need to get the value from the last available date before the selected start date.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2012?

Comment: No not yet, but would still like to know what I could do with 2012, what I can't with 2005/2008. However it is not an option for some users of the system. 2005 is lowest, and will remain a while.

Comment: I would try inserting the recursive dates CTE into a temp table - there's a chance that SQL will rematerialize it more than once (and the result seems static).

Comment: Can you provide DDL and sample data for the objects referenced in the query?

Comment: To go along with what @StuartLC said, I'd recommend creating a full, permanent Calendar table, especially if you do a lot of date querying (or have additional needs, say "Fiscal Period").  There's examples all over the place for usable columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make this more efficient.  You are doing a whole bunch of correlated non-equijoins and then counting the results.

Take a different approach.  One simple approach would be to summarize `ExaminationCTE` by date, to summarize the results.  However, in SQL Server, the CTE isn't materialized so this might not change the performance.

Another way is to do the count using window functions.  Here is an example for the first field:

```
from dates left outer join
     (select createdate, max(seqnum) as examinations_created_count
      from (select createdate, row_number() over (order by createdate) as seqnum
            from ExaminationCTE
           ) e
      group by createdate
     ) ecc
     on dates.date = ecc.createdate
```

The others would be similiar.  In fact, you can put all the variables in one subquery.

The logic is to add a sequential number to each row and then take the maximum number per date.  This is the count.

Comment: I see that you are right about the fact that I should count, records that are already counted don't matter anymore, however I don't know how to implement this in SQL, do you?

Comment: It sounds good, but the query doesn't work. It throws an error about `Column 'e.createdate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` and when adding the group by clause all the counts are `NULL`

Comment: I really tried but will not get the expected results with this query

Comment: @NickN. . . . is `createdate` a date or datetime?  I assumed from the name that it is a date.

Comment: It was indeed a datetime, and that was causing the problem. I changed it now, but still not the expected results:(

Comment: I know the problem now, the dates that aren't in the joined queries will get a NULL value while they must have the same value as the last found date, do you know how to do this?

Comment: @NickN. . . . Except for the `on` clauses, get the date values from `dates`.

Comment: I don't need the second date actually, only need the first date and the count:) but I decided to do in code, so thanks:)